# How do German-speaking children learn cases and adjective endings?

Tags: learning

I ask because these rules give adult learners no end of headache, so how does a child learn them?

A child hears "schönes Wetter", and learns that.
Next time when she says "schönes Hund", how do the parents correct her? Surely they don't enter into a  discussion of noun gender with a 2 year old?

Then how do the parents stop her from saying "das schönes Wetter?"

And how does the child learn that the definite article changes in accusatives for masculine nouns but not for feminine or neuter? And if at any point the child asks "why?", what do the parents say without going into lengthy grammar discussion?

Comment: This question is more suited to [linguistics.stackexchange.com](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: They'll say "This question is specific to German, so go post there".

Comment: This works the same in all languages. English doesn't have cases the way German has, but it has e. g. irregular verbs which pose similar problems to the learner.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't have anything to do with the german language specifically. You could as well ask how japanese or finnish children learn these complicated languages so easy.

Answer (score 3):

People copy what they hear. If the first couple of times they say *"schönes Hund"* and parents say it differently, they copy that without even knowing they learned something right now.

> Next time when she says "schönes Hund", how do the parents correct her?

By saying *"it's not schönes Hund but schöner Hund"*. That's it.
I never heard parents tell their kids *"we say that because of rule xy"*. I even doubt many parents know much about rules or the correct terms they would need to eplain them.
Even more I have never seen a child in an age learing to speak who wants to know grammar rules or would be able to understand them.

It's the same with children learning a foreign language not at school but in reality in a foreign country.
While some - not only kids but also adults - might not dare to speak outside, instead spend time at home to memorize rules and have headaches, others go out and talk to other people.
This can result in horribly wrong attempts in the beginning but becomes better the more they talk. Just by doing, getting told how it's correct and listening what others say.

It's also the same with spelling words.
People who read a lot get used to words they read, then adapt how those words are spelled without much realizing that. They don't think about rules when it comes to write a word, they write it out of their mind.

(can't resist to say that... but look at social media. These days when things are not primarily written by professionals like newspaper, books, other texts but when every dork posts things into social media in their own guessed spelling, others have no more chance to adapt correct language any more)

Answer (score 3):

- How do English-speaking children learn that complicated system of grammatical tenses?
- How do English-speaking children learn the different types of if-sentences?
- How do English-speaking children learn that non-intuitive ordering rules of adjectives?
- How do English-speaking children learn how to pronounce that strange *th*-sounds?

This (and many more) are problems that German native speakers have when they learn English as a foreign language. Did you have major troubles with that when you learned English as a child? Probably not.

Children listen and then reproduce what they heard. (have heard? did hear? This is what I struggle with for more than 40 years). They build implicit rules in their brains. They do not know what is correct or wrong. Correct and wrong are not categories of their thinking. They just build an ever rising set of rules with exceptions and exceptions of exception. And they are not aware of that rules in their brains.

Ask an average English native speaker (who is not a teacher or has a theoretical approach to the language for any other reason) about the ordering rules for adjectives in English nominative groups. Most of them will not be able to tell you that rules. Many even will not know that there are such rules. But all of them can tell you, which of these two sentences is correct and which is wrong:

> I love this beautiful little old red Italian car.
> I love this red Italian little old beautiful car.

German native speakers have to learn such rules when they want to speak and write proper english, because these rules exist and even more important: because they are used by English native speakers. And it is hard to learn these rules, because German has different and less strict rules.

So, how do little children who grew up in an English speaking environment learn those rules?

They just listen and reproduce. Listen, listen more, and reproduce again and listen even more and reproduce more. They do not learn rules from a book or from a teacher. They listen and talk. And they do not care about being wrong. They just talk and talk and listen and listen.

And this is what you should do too: Listen to native speakers, talk to native speakers, and don't care much about errors.

And another very important tip: Do NOT translate in your head from one language to another. THINK in the language that you want to learn. That's what children do too. Even if they grow up bilingual, they do not translate. When they listen to someone, they think in the language of the speaker. And when they speak, they speak in the language in which they are thinking.

I know my English is not the best, and I make lot's of mistakes. I'm a German native speaker. (I am 55 years old now and I had my first English lesson when I was 10.) But I wouldn't be able to write texts like this here, if I was thinking in German and then translating it into German. (Or is it *"if I were thinking"*, or maybe *"if I did think"?* Again: more than 40 years of struggling with that.) I do not translate. I think in English. And I make errors, although I try to avoid as many of them as I can.

---

You also asked about "why":

When a German speaking child asks its<sub>*("child" is neuter in German)*</sub> parents:

> Warum ist der Löffel männlich? Warum ist die Gabel weiblich? Und warum ist das Messer sächlich?
> <sup>*Why is the spoon male? Why is the fork female? And why is the knife neuter?*</sup>

German speaking parents will answer:

> You can ask silly questions! They just are how they are. Why is a ball round and why has a cube corners? Things are as they are. Now go and clean up your room.

Comment: The (unrequested) advice in the second part of the answer is dangerous. *Ungesteuerter Spracherwerb* is liable to produce *Fließend-Falsch-Sprecher*.

Comment: Case in point: "lot´s".